# change the color of the button I clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created to buttons in each row.
the user will click any one of it.
if they click success the function sends a mail to the user regarding the payment.
if they click reverted the function send a mail to the user regarding the revert.
this is working fine.
My problem is when I click on success or reverted BUTTONS the button color should change to green after function but weather I click on success or reverted only success button color is changing
This Is My HTML Table

```
<tr>
                        <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["accountnumber"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["net"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["cheque_no"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["cheque_date"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["tds"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["cgst1"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["sgst1"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["igst_tds"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["cess"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["Description"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["mail"].'</td>
                        
                        
                        
                        <td>
                        <input type="button" name="Success" class="btn btn-info btn-xs email_button" id="'.$count.'" data-email="'.$row["mail"].'" data-name="'.$row["name"].'" data-net="'.$row["net"].'" data-net="'.$row["net"].'"
                            data-cheque_no="'.$row["cheque_no"].'"
                            data-cheque_date="'.$row["cheque_date"].'"
                            data-tds="'.$row["tds"].'"
                            data-cgst1="'.$row["cgst1"].'"
                            data-sgst1="'.$row["sgst1"].'"
                            data-igst_tds="'.$row["igst_tds"].'"
                            data-cess="'.$row["cess"].'"
                            data-description="'.$row["Description"].'"
                            data-accountnumber="'.$row["accountnumber"].'"
                            data-sum="'.$row["sum"].'"
                            data-id="'.$row["id"].'"
                            data-action="single" 
                            data-stat="success" value="Transaction Success">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        
                        
                        <input type="button" name="Reverted" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs reverted_button"
                        id="'.$count.'" data-email="'.$row["mail"].'" data-name="'.$row["name"].'" data-net="'.$row["net"].'" data-net="'.$row["net"].'"
                            data-cheque_no="'.$row["cheque_no"].'"
                            data-cheque_date="'.$row["cheque_date"].'"
                            data-tds="'.$row["tds"].'"
                            data-cgst1="'.$row["cgst1"].'"
                            data-sgst1="'.$row["sgst1"].'"
                            data-igst_tds="'.$row["igst_tds"].'"
                            data-cess="'.$row["cess"].'"
                            data-description="'.$row["Description"].'"
                            data-accountnumber="'.$row["accountnumber"].'"
                            data-sum="'.$row["sum"].'"
                            data-id="'.$row["id"].'" data-reverted="reverted" data-action="Reverse" value ="Reverted"> </td>
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    </tr>
```

This Is My script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.email_button').click(function(){
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        var id  = $(this).attr("id");
        var action = $(this).data("action");
        var email_data = [];
        if(action == 'single')
        {
            email_data.push({
                email: $(this).data("email"),
                name: $(this).data("name"),
                        net: $(this).data("net"),
                id: $(this).data("id"),
                        cheque_no: $(this).data("cheque_no"),
                        cheque_date: $(this).data("cheque_date"),
                        tds: $(this).data("tds"),
                        cgst1: $(this).data("cgst1"),
                        sgst1: $(this).data("sgst1"),
                        igst_tds: $(this).data("igst_tds"),
                        cess: $(this).data("cess"),
                        description: $(this).data("description"),
                        sum: $(this).data("sum"),
                        accountnumber: $(this).data("accountnumber")
            });
        }
        $.ajax({
            url:"send_mail.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{email_data:email_data},
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#'+id).html('Sending...');
                $('#'+id).addClass('btn-danger');
            },
            success:function(data){
                if(data == 'ok')
                {
                    $('#'+id).text('Success');
                    $('#'+id).removeClass('btn-danger');
                    $('#'+id).removeClass('btn-info');
                    $('#'+id).addClass('btn-success');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#'+id).text(data);
                }
                $('#'+id).attr('disabled', false);
            }
        })  

    });
}); 
    </script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.reverted_button').click(function(){
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        var id1  = $(this).attr("id");
        var action1 = $(this).data("action");
        var email_data3 = [];
        if(action1 == 'Reverse')
        {
            email_data3.push({
                email: $(this).data("email"),
                name: $(this).data("name"),
                        net: $(this).data("net"),
                id: $(this).data("id"),
                        cheque_no: $(this).data("cheque_no"),
                        cheque_date: $(this).data("cheque_date"),
                        tds: $(this).data("tds"),
                        cgst1: $(this).data("cgst1"),
                        sgst1: $(this).data("sgst1"),
                        igst_tds: $(this).data("igst_tds"),
                        cess: $(this).data("cess"),
                        description: $(this).data("description"),
                        sum: $(this).data("sum"),
                        accountnumber: $(this).data("accountnumber")
            });
        }
        

        $.ajax({
            url:"send_mail1.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{email_data3:email_data3},
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#'+id1).html('Sending...');
                $('#'+id1).addClass('btn-danger');
            },
            success:function(data){
                if(data == 'ok')
                {
                    $('#'+id1).text('Success');
                    $('#'+id1).removeClass('btn-danger');
                    $('#'+id1).removeClass('btn-info');
                    $('#'+id1).addClass('btn-success');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#'+id1).text(data);
                }
                $('#'+id1).attr('disabled', false);
            }
        })  

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you understand that none of this is java?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class for a button being clicked, like say ".buttonClicked" – which sets (& overrides) the background styles of an unclicked button. Then do:

```
$('.email_button,.reverted_button').click(function(){
    // …do whatever…
    $(this).addClass('buttonClicked');
    // …do more
})
```